Attachment not saved for Contribution
We have a custom field of type file for a contribution. We use this field to store invoices for payment. After we did the CiviCRM upgrade to 5.73.1, the field stopped saving the file. We upgraded CiviCRM from 5.65.1 to 5.73.1, is there anything changed that we are not aware of to make the field again?

looks like a core bug

Thanks for confirming, Any quick solution to fix it? Should we rollback the upgrade?

I have added my answer

Thanks, Pradeep, for issuing the patch so quickly. I encountered a similar issue with a custom file-type field linked to the Participant table. Does your patch cover this situation as well?

I have submitted a fix for the issue, you can either wait for the release or apply the patch

Nice work Pradeep!
